# Can I replace an ER107 for an IN4007 or IN4005?

Tags: diodes

I am trying to repair a Power Supply where 2 resistances and one diode got burned, that diode was a ER107.

I was looking at the datasheets and the things that change are the Forward Voltage, Peak Voltage and DC Blocking. I dont know if I can use the IN4007 or the IN4005 to replace it or If I shouldn't.

Comment: It's 1N4007 - similarly, 2N3055 for a particular transistor..

Answer (score 1):

ER107 Vfm= 1.3V (max) @ 1A,  Vr=500Vdc, Cj= 10 pF @4V,  100uA @ 100'C @ 500V

1N4005 Vf= 1.1V  (max(  @ 1A, Vr= 600Vdc, Cj < 10pF @ 4 V,  50uA @ 100'C @ 600V
so it is better for all specs, also 1N4007 Vr=1kV

Comment: So, It will be better if I use IN4007?

Comment: no it is not better  it has slightly higher Vf, therefore hotter

Comment: Hmmm then can I use the IN4005 without problems or not?

Comment: Hmm. Did you not understand my answer?   1N4005 is better but 1N4007 is ok

Comment: Could I use NTE125?

Comment: Can  you compare specs?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. ER107, according to [this](http://www.senocn.com/data/PDF/ER101-ER108.pdf) datasheet has a trr of 35ns compared to several microseconds (not specified) for the 1N4007. The latter is maybe more than 100x worse.

Thus a 1N4007 is likely to **burn up** and destroy other parts in the process. They're using a more expensive super-fast-recovery rectifier instead of a cheap 1N4007 **for a reason**.

I suggest using a [SBYV26C-E3/54](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88735/sbyv26c.pdf).

Comment: Hmmm could I use NTE125?

Comment: No, it's a standard recovery like a 1N4007. Even a UF4007 (my go-to choice for cheap through hole 1A fast recovery) is significantly slower. For shopping you can go to a distie like Digikey, search for 600V PIV, 1A current and 35ns or so (**or less**) reverse recovery time. You should find a small handful of choices.